# one record doesn't store into mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, html

i am trying to store user records into my table user , there is a strange problem happening right now which all data is stored but not the `address` record.

here is my form code

```
function RegisterUser($firstName,$LastName,$Gender,$Address,$phoneNumber,$mobileNumber,$facebookAccount,$userName,$password,$emailAddress) {

    $dob = $_POST['Year'] . '-' . $_POST['Month'] . '-' .$_POST['Day'];

$insertVisitor = "INSERT INTO user (userFirstName,userLastName,userDateOfBirth,userGender,userAddress,userPhoneNumber,userMobileNumber,userFacebookAccount,userUserName,userPassword,userEmailAddress) VALUES ('$FirstName','$LastName','$dob','$Gender','$Address','$phoneNumber','$mobileNumber','$facebookAccount','$userName','$password','$emailAddress')";

mysql_query("$insertVisitor") or die (mysql_error());



}
```

i made sure of the following

- the form `field address` is `textarea` and the same name is variable `$Address` on my action file.
- in mysql database , the record userAdddress is text type and has default 0 length.

what is it i did wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to `$address` in the SQL, while the parameter says `$Address`.

Variables are case-sensitive.

```
function RegisterUser($firstName,$LastName,$Gender,$Address, ...
                                                    ^
$insertVisitor = "INSERT INTO user .... ,'$address','$phoneNumber', .. )"
                                           ^
```

Quick note (possible mysql-injection aside): `$insertVisitor` is already a string, so you don't have to quote it again:

```
mysql_query("$insertVisitor") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query($insertVisitor) or die(mysql_error()); //<--
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing you did wrong was open yourself to a gaping SQL injection hole.

Second thing is that PHP variables are case sensitive. Your function's argument list has `$Address` (capital A), and you're using `$address` (small A) in the query string. So you're using a completely different variable, which doesn't exist, causing PHP to auto-instantiate it as a blank value.

Answer (score 1):

Your text field for userAddress should have a length greater than 0 - try setting it to what you would expect for an address such as 100 characters.

Comment: i tried this but the database keep change it again to 0 length .

Answer (score 1):

The function gets `$Address` and in your query you try to get `$address` which are 2 different variables since the PHP variables are case sensitive.

Comment: i change it but the problem remains

Comment: You get any errors or is just the field blank in the database?